# What is the "===!" operator doing?

Tags: javascript, operators

I'am playing with some JavaScript and found something strange.

This code alerts "false" but gives no syntax errors. Someone could explain why adding one or even many `!!!` after `===` is no resulting with any errors ?

```
var i = void 0;
var b = i ===! void 0  ? "true" : "false";
alert(b);//display false but no syntax errors..
```

Comment: `!` is negating the following statement, even if the following statement is an `!`

Comment: And why should it? `!` is just a negation, so multiple `!` will just invert each other

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Whitespace means nothing so it is

```
var b = (i === (!void 0))  ? "true" : "false";
```

which is

```
var b = (i === true) ? "true" : "false";
```

[MDN Operator Precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

Comment: For clarity, I might also include `i === true; // false` (perhaps brackets around it)

Answer (score 5):

`!` is just a negation, and it is right-associative, unlike most other operators, so it will just negate whatever is in front of it

This is essentially equivalent to

`var b = i ===(!void 0)  ? "true" : "false";`

So basically, you could have as many `!`s in front of something as you want, and it wouldn't make a difference, so `!!!!!!!!!!!!!false`, would evaluate to true, because it is the same thing as `!(!(!(!(!(!(!(!(!(!(!(!(!false))))))))))))`

Comment: @user2864740 haha, whoops, I was testing that on a page where `i` was previously defined

Comment: I'll just assume you put in the right number of `!(...)` and upvote :)

Comment: @AdamRackis I took great pains to put in the right number of parens

Comment: @scrblnrd3 and great pains to you to count them :)

Answer (score 2):

See this table, which may help explain:

```
!0 // true
!!0 // false
!!!!!!0 // false, showing that !s are simply prefixes
! 0 // true, showing whitespace is irrelevant
0 === !0 // false
0 ===! 0 // false
0 ===!!! 0 // false
```